# How to convert XML to hash map ignoring parent-child relationships

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

I have this XML:

```
<XmlParent>
    <name>koraytugay</name>
    <bar>
        <baz>
            <to>Tove</to>
            <qux>00000001</qux>
        </baz>
    </bar>
    <note>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
</XmlParent>
```

I want to search for "to" and "from" and extract that data
The XML format will not always be the same, but "from" and "to" will always be present (The actual nodes to look for will be configured in a properties file)

The way I intend to do this is by transforming into a json file so I would want it to look like this

```
{
    to:Tove
    qux:00000001
    from:Jani
    heading:Reminder
    body:Don't forget me this weekend!
}
```

Currently I'm getting it like this

```
    XmlParent:
    {
        name:koraytugay
        bar:
        {
            baz: 
            {
                to:Tove
                qux:00000001
            }
        }
        note:
        {
            from:Jani
            heading:Reminder
            body:Don't forget me this weekend!
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple different methods. 
I have an XSD that looks like this (Removed actual data from schema tag but this is working fine)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns=""
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns=""
    targetNamespace=""
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
            Initial Draft
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="XMLExample">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This is what I'm currently doing

```
private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(XmlConverter.class);

    public Map<String, Object> xmlStringToHashMap(String xml) {
        JSON json = xmlStringToJSON(xml);

        return jsonToMap(json.toString(2));

    }

    public Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String jsonString) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {

            Map<String, Object> jsonInMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });

            LOGGER.info("JSON Map created: " + jsonInMap);

            return jsonInMap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public JSON xmlStringToJSON(String xml) {
        XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        return xmlSerializer.read(xml);

    }
```

Any idea how to add the elements and their data into one JSON file or HashMap whilst ignoring parent tags?

Comment: Try Xpath  expressions like `//to/text()` to get the content of the `<to>` element anywhere in the XML document.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this done?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the XPath expression `//to/text()`

Here's my solution:

```
private String[] elements;

    public Map<String, Object> xPathParser(String xmlString) {
        try {
            Document xmlDoc = xmlStringToDocument(xmlString);

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression;
            Map<String, Object> elements = new HashMap<>();
            for (String element : elements) {
                expression = MessageFormat.format("//{0}/text()", element);

                Object xpathValue = xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);

                elements.put(element, xpathValue);
            }

            return elements;

        } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html), a Java library to parse HTML or XML. I use it often when I want to get the job done without having to write a colossal amount of code. For your given example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class NewClass3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<XmlParent>\n" +
                        "    <name>koraytugay</name>\n" +
                        "    <bar>\n" +
                        "        <baz>\n" +
                        "            <to>Tove</to>\n" +
                        "            <qux>00000001</qux>\n" +
                        "        </baz>\n" +
                        "    </bar>\n" +
                        "    <note>\n" +
                        "        <from>Jani</from>\n" +
                        "        <heading>Reminder</heading>\n" +
                        "        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n" +
                        "    </note>\n" +
                        "</XmlParent>";

        Document doc    = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        Element to      = doc.selectFirst("to");
        Element from    = doc.selectFirst("from");
        Element qux     = doc.selectFirst("qux");
        Element heading = doc.selectFirst("heading");
        Element body    = doc.selectFirst("body");

        //print put in map or whatever...
        System.out.println("to: "   + to.text());
        System.out.println("from: " + qux.text());

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("to", to.text());
    }    
}
```